# Pythonでマウス操作を監視し、選択されたファイルのパスをチェックする方法

Tags: python

「マウスでドラッグ＆ドロップされたファイルをソフトウェアに読み込む」という処理を行いたいです。

PythonでWindowsまたはMacでのマウス操作を監視して
・デスクトップ等でファイルがクリックされたことを検知
・ファイルパスを取得
・マウスが離されたことを検知

のような処理を書く方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: Windowsならマウスの動きそのものはこれら [pythonでpyHookを使ってキーロガーを作る (Windows)](https://chindafalldesu.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/01/03/161250),[Detecting Mouse clicks in windows using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/165495/9014308), [Using python with windows 10 to enable mouse wraparound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60641210/9014308) で出来るでしょうが、クリックされたものが何であるかは、(それが選択動作なのかも含めて)対象のアプリケーションとかWindowsの画面上で何に該当するかの情報が取得出来るかにかかってきて、一筋縄ではいかないと思われます。RPAでの基となる操作記録を取りたいとかでしょうか。

Comment: 「RPAでの基となる操作記録」というのが何を意味するのか分からないのですが、ファイルダイアログを開かずにファイルを取り扱いたいという願望があります。

Comment: 質問を見た勝手な想像でRPA(RoboticProcessAutomation)つまり作業手順の自動化のために、その基となる手作業を記録するのでは？と思った次第です。

Answer (score 4):

マウス操作を監視するのではなく、PythonのGUIアプリケーションにマウスでドラッグ＆ドロップされたファイルを読み込む処理ならばファイルダイアログを開かずにファイルを取り扱うことができます。
そのためには[TkDND](https://www.ellogon.org/petasis/index.php/tcltk-projects/tkdnd)などの外部パッケージが必要です。(事前準備を参照してインストールしてください)

参考資料: [【Python】tkinter：ファイルのドラッグアンドドロップ（パス取得、画像表示）](https://office54.net/python/tkinter/file-drag-drop)

**事前準備**

```
pip install tkinterdnd2
```

**サンプルコード**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD as tdnd
from tkinterdnd2 import DND_FILES

# ドロップイベント
def drop(event: tdnd.DnDEvent):
    label = event.widget
    label.configure(text = event.data)
    print(label.labelText)

w = tdnd.Tk()
label = ttk.Label(w, text="ここにファイルをドロップすると\nパスを表示します")
label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# ラベルをファイルのドラッグアンドドロップに対応させる
label.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
label.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)

w.mainloop()
```

以下はPCに詳しい人向けの蛇足です。

デスクトップやエクスプローラで、どのファイルがクリックやドロップされたのかを検知する実装はあまり現実的ではありません。
[pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)などの外部パッケージでマウスの動作を監視できますが、クリック位置情報からファイルパスを取得する処理がとても難しいです。

画面ではなく特定のフォルダにドラッグアンドドロップやコピーしたことを検知する実装で代替可能ならば[Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)パッケージを導入してフォルダ監視する方法もあります。

D&Dは案外操作コストが高いので、Windowsならば右クリックの「送る」メニューにPythonプログラムを配置して、引数で受け取ったフルパスを処理する方法も実用に耐えるかもしれません。
ただしWindows11標準のコンテキストメニューでは「送る」メニューが隠れていて(未確認)結局使いにくいような…。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Tkinterを使う場合は使えそうですうね。ただ、Windows標準のメモ帳など、多くのソフトがファイルのドラッグ＆ドロップに対応しているのに、何故Pythonでは簡単には出来ないのかがちょっと疑問です。クリックやドロップを検知しているわけではなく、別の手段を使用しているのでしょうか？